# How to create click event using angular directive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am very new to creating AngularJs directive , so below i have created directive and when user click on delete button i am checking what are the values of scope,element and attrs but its not printing anything in console. ProcessDTO is the json data in the controller.

Any idea what i am missing here, i have read the directive documentation but if someone can put some light and explain it as beginner level it would be great.

html

```
<button class="btn btn-danger"
        type="button" autodelete delete-tags="processDTO">Delete</button>
```

directive.js

```
angular.module('App').directive('autoDelete', function () {
    'use strict';
    return{
      restrict:'A',
      scope:{
      autoDeleteTags: '=deleteTags'
      },
      link:function(scope,element,attr){
        $(element).click(function(){
          console.log('Element',element);
          console.log('SCOPE',scope);
          console.log('ATTRS',attr);
        })
      }
  }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directive named `autoDelete` is looking for attribute `auto-delete` not `autodelete`

Try:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger"
        type="button" auto-delete delete-tags="processDTO">Delete</button>
```

Also would suggest using `ng-click` instead of creating your own event handlers

Comment: Thanks that resolve the problem , but for attr it should print json object correct ? I dont see the object from controller.

Comment: Not really clear what you are asking. `attr.deleteTags` would be  string == `"processDTO"`

Comment: may be i should ask if i have processDTO object in controller how can i access that in directive i thought we are accessing through attr.deleteTags.

Comment: Great i can see that printing scope.autoDeleteTags, Thank you